# Updating an BehaviorSubject based on User Input in Angular 5

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject

I have some default data for a table that is being fetched by a service and stored in a behaviorSubject. The user has the option to add more rows to the table by entering fields in a form. How can I update the Observable to include the user-created data? Or is there a better way to update the data?

I was trying to get the value of the current b.s. and concat the new item and then use next() to update the b.s. but I couldn't get it to work.

***Edit***

vincecampanale had some good points and helped me move the code along but now I'm just getting a 'currentItems.concat is not a function error' even though it was initialized as an array, what else am I missing?

Updated Code:

```
defaults = this.http.get(this.url);

private defaultItems = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.defaults);
items = this.defaultItems.asObservable();

addItem(item: object) {
    let currentItems = [];
    currentItems = this.defaultItems.getValue();
    let updatedItems = currentItems.concat(item);
    this.defaultItems.next(updatedItems);
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you be providing `updatedItems` variable into the `next()` method instead of `product`?

Answer (score 1):

The `defaultItems` property holds an array of products, so pass it the array containing the default items in addition to the new product, which is `updatedItems` in your example:

```
this.defaultItems.next(updatedItems);
```

Also, [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the `length` of the new array, not the array itself. Use [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to get the array resulting from adding `product` to `currentItems`:

```
let updatedItems = currentItems.concat(item);
```

Finally, it appears the method ought to add the parameter `item` to the array, not `product`.

The new `addItem` method with these changes applied:

```
addItem(item: object) {
  let currentItems = this.defaultItems.getValue();
  let updatedItems = currentItems.concat(item);
  this.defaultItems.next(item);
}
```